# get the running chrome apps from background page

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chromium, google-chrome-os

I it possible to get the currently running chrome apps from a chrome extension background page ?
I am able to get the list of installed apps, but how can I know what apps are now running ?

Answer (score 1):

Check this [steps](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1184722?hl=en) if this is the one you are looking for.

1. On your computer, open Chrome.
2. At the top right, click More or Settings.
3. Click More tools and then Task manager.
4. In the first column, look for items labeled "Background Page." You can see its details in the other columns.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late, but chrome.debugger.getTargets() works. Just do that, then filter by type === 'other' and url.startsWith('chrome-extension').